# Google app engine deploy flask app - ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, opencv, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a python flask app to google cloud. Once the app starts running I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/vmagent/app/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Doing some research on the problem, I figured out that this seems to be a problem related to opencv-python and the following line should fixes the issue on linux:

```
sudo apt-get install libsm6
```

However, since I am using Mac I am unable to use apt-get to install libsm6 locally and since I am deploying using a requirements.txt file which does not accept apt-get I am stuck fixing this. I tried to SSH into the running instance on google cloud, however it does not accept apt-get install libsm6 either, telling me I lack admin rights:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

changing directory to root didn't help either. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have also tried python version 3.5 and 3.4 with no luck.

Comment: The post appear to suggest flex env. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, in my app.yaml it says 'env: flex' - as it is suggested in the flask demo on google cloud

Answer (score 2):

From this info I assume you are not using a virtual environment. If Google Cloud gives you this error is because the python package you are referencing is not installed in /lib of your project. If you follow this [Getting started guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env) you will notice that it advises first of creating a virtual env and then using the requirements.txt file to basically replicate that exact environment on Google Apps, hence the

```
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

My advise is to follow closely the getting started AND the github example and notice differences in terms of pip install in lib folder.

**Update**: Looking more closely at the stack trace the problem seems to originate from cv2 library depending on libSM.so.6 which is a C library. Google App Engine is very picky with regards to C libraries in python projects.

Suggestion is to try to use an alternative library for whatever cv2 does, a library that is pure Python.

Comment: I am using anaconda, as such I am using a conda virtual environment. Is that okay as well? I have been following the guide closely, as such I have installed all modules using the 'pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt' command, which generates a lib folder with all of them inside. However upon deployment the code throws me the error seen above. On the other hand, if I use the requirements.txt file to install the modules for my virtual env locally, everything works just fine.

Comment: @AaronDT What I can sa it's that libSM.so libraries are C libraries that are not always installed in the machine that is given to you on the Cloud. You cannot possibly install C libraries in your Google App Engine environment and it looks like cv2 depends on this .so library.  Suggestion: Try to use a library that is purely python to do the same you were trying to do with cv2

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the flexible environment you can create a custom runtime based on the corresponding google-supplied docker image in which you add the additional dependencies your app require. From [About Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes):

> Custom runtimes allow you to define new runtime environments, which
>   might include additional components like language interpreters or
>   application servers.

See also [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).

Comment: That is an interesting option I wasn't aware of, thank you very much! Do I understand the docs correctly that I would have to dockerize my app on my own before deployment in order to create a custom runtime? From looking at my console log during deployment, it appears to me that using 'gcloud app deploy' does dockerize my app before trying to boot it, as such I would like to access the image that google cloud has created - however I can't find any information on how to access that image. Using 'docker images' in the projects console on google cloud shows no results.

Comment: flex uses docker anyways. It's just a matter of customizing the image to use. There are pointers to the base/standard images in the 2nd reference. You just provide the custom dockerfile to use instead of the standard one.